# Fully indenting second and subsequent paragraphs inside table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs, xtab

I am using the following setup to typeset a table that will eventually contain too many rows to fit on one page thus using `xtabular` from the `xtab` package.  Conceptually, I have multiple sub-rows inside each row but I want the table to not break the page inside these rows, so resorted to adding line breaks with `\newline` to create these sub-rows such that the "outer" table rows contain the potential break points for `xtabular`.

Now I want the following layout inside one row/cell: how can I make the whole row/cell "hanging" as in adding extra horizontal space to the 2nd and subsequent paragraphs.  See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab} % for tables spanning multiple pages
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}{|L{7cm}|}
short first par\newline
  longer paragraph that should be ragged right and fully indented\newline
  third paragraph also indented \\ % this is the row end for tabular
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

Looking at the output from the MWE, I want the second and subsequent paragraphs be fully indented (not just hanging or first line indent) as indicated by the orange line and arrow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\def\zz{\def\par{\endgraf\leftskip1em\let\par\endgraf}}
\usepackage{xtab} % for tables spanning multiple pages
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\zz
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}{|L{7cm}|}
short first par

  longer paragraph that should be ragged right and fully indented

  third paragraph also indented \\ % this is the row end for tabular
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the bulk of your tabular content is indented. So, an alternative approach would be to only adjust your heading (short) paragraph text via a negative indent (or `\undent`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,xtab}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\undent}{\hspace*{-15pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}{|@{\hspace{\dimexpr15pt+\tabcolsep}}L{7cm}|}
  \undent short first par

    longer paragraph that should be ragged right and fully indented

    third paragraph also indented \\

  \undent short first par

    longer paragraph that should be ragged right and fully indented

    third paragraph also indented \\
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

The `15pt` space comes from the default `\parindent` (which resets to `0pt` within a the `xtabular`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after crafting the question, it occurred to me to abuse the hanging of paragraphs by declaring the hanging to occur after line 0.  Not pretty but it works.  Still open to any cleaner ideas!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab} % for tables spanning multiple pages
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}{|L{7.5cm}|}
short first par\newline\everypar{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=0}
  longer paragraph that should be ragged right and fully indented\newline
  third paragraph also indented \\ % this is the row end for tabular
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: why use `\newline` for a paragraph break? rather than a blank line as usual?  `\newline` is intended for linebreaks within the same paragraph.